# Coexistence Testing for Consumer grade RF and ECG Systems

Tags: emc, ecg, lte

How are ECG (electrocardiogram) systems tested on wearable products to show no coexistence issue RF systems?

Specifically I am trying to understand if the products are tested with ECG electrodes terminated in some way or not? It seems to me that the body contact could be an important part of the entire noise coupling mechanism and I am not aware of body phantoms that would work to mimic conducted and radiated properties at both LTE and ECG frequencies.  As a specific example how does the Apple Watch test the ECG system for EMC/EMI compliance to specifications such as IEC 61000 to show that an external aggressor is not impacting the ECG measurement in some malicious way?

Comment: I have been playing with hobbyist grade 2.4G and also ECG which is below 200Hz. Usually the chips has a built in low frequency filter (including 50/60Hz band cut. Refs: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98416/how-can-rpi-read-data-of-a-heart-rate-sensor-module-such-as-ad8232/98417#98417
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111426/reducing-sound-noise-when-recording-with-pi
(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96482/ecg-monitoring-using-ads8232-and-mcp3008-noise-problem

Answer (score 1):

ECG could be measured optically by reflections or electrically with more noise from galvanic skin vibration.   RF is pretty easy to filter using using low frequencies sensors if well-designed to some specs. Of course there may always be a threshold that can be exceeded with a high power Radar pulse.